# Установка шрифтов windows на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os

Установил Ubuntu (elementary os).

Но очень привык к шрифтам windows.

Сделал по этой инструкции https://itisgood.ru/2018/07/11/ustanovka-shriftov-microsoft-windows-v-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

После через gnome-tweaks установил везде шрифт Tahoma 9.

Но все равно вид шрифта отличается как-то, то ли жирнее он, из-за этого глаза устают.

Сравниваю на странице сайта, захожу на один и тот же сайт через chrome с windows 10 и Ubuntu.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Без шансов. Сглаживание шрифтов в Window и unix отличаются.

Comment: Можно поиграться с настройками, но абсолютного сходства не будет https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/font_configuration#Fontconfig_configuration

Comment: В винде по умолчанию давно Segoe UI, вы уверены что вам нужна именно Tahoma?

Comment: И да, если вы сравниваете страницу сайта - значит предварительно проверьте, какой шрифт прописан в этой самой странице